# How do I merge all the elements of a MATLAB array into a string?

Tags: string, matlab, matrix

If I have something like this:

```
m = [0 1 0 0 1 1]
```

I want to turn it into

```
s = '010011'
```

In Python, it's so easy:

```
m = [0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1]
s = ''.join(m)
# s = '010011'
```

How do I do it in MATLAB?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remember that Python does type conversions automatically - Matlab (and most other languages) is a little more picky.  Thus, you will need to do the type conversion manually on every element of your array. I believe

```
myString = sprintf('%1d', m);
```

should do it - although I can't actually check it as I don't have matlab on my computer at home.  Try it - tell me if that doesn't work for you.

Answer (score 1):

I think an alternate way could be this:

```
s=num2str(m);
s(s==' ')='';
```

or

```
s=regexprep(num2str(m),'[^\w]','')
```